# hibernate envers alter REVINFO table name

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm using hibernate envers 4 and I would like to change the REVINFO table name. 
Is that feasible? If yes, how?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom revision entity (annotate it with `@RevisionEntity`) and then you can specify the name of the table in the usual way.

See also [Envers docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-revisionlog).